# Trying to force a div to the top of a page

Tags: css

Hi have had to put the menu bar further down the page so javascript will load a slide show.

I am trying to then push the menu bar up. Can I put in an absolute reference so it appears a t the top.

```
#left, #middle, #right {
    background-color: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

#left {
    width: 15%;
    min-width: 10em;
    padding-left: 5px;
    background: #fff; 
}


#middle {
    width: 80%;
    border-left: 3px dotted #999;; 
    background: #fff;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    background: #666;
}


#footer {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}

#left2 {
    width: 15%;
    min-width: 10em;
    padding-left: 5px;
    background: #fff; 
    margin-top: -500px
}
#middle2 {
    width: 80%;
    border-left: 3px dotted #999;; 
padding top: 500px  
}
```

In Html

```
<div id="middle2">

<div id="left2">
```

Comment: There appears to be a syntax error in the declaration of the style for `#middle`.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is completely unclear in your code what the 'menu bar' is, or which class might apply to it, it seems to me you should try absolute positioning in CSS

CSS:

```
.menubar
{
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:20px;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="some_menu_bar" class="menubar">
  your menu goes here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to then push the menu bar up.

This makes me think you hope to delay the positioning of the menu bar until some script has executed. You cannot do this with CSS alone*.

*Ok perhaps you can with CSS3 and animations but this isn't well supported at the moment.